# what all ways to define a class level method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to have a ruby class where all methods I require, that are class methods, and hence I defined them as `def self.method_name`, and now all methods are defined as `self.` Is there any way to avoid writing `self.`, and in one go declare all methods as class level.

One is to put them in a module and let the class extend it.

What else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def class_method_name1
    end

    def class_method_name2
    end
  end

  def instance_method_name1
  end

  def self.class_method_name3
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts 'class method'
  end

  def baz
    puts 'instance method'
  end
end

Foo.bar # => "class method"
Foo.baz # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘baz’ for Foo:Class

Foo.new.baz # => instance method
Foo.new.bar # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘bar’ for #<Foo:0x1e820>
```